# how to install the PostgreSQL build infrastructure for extensions called PGXS on windows 10?

Tags: postgresql, installation, windows-10

When installing PostgreSQL 13 and 14, it seems that the EDB installer for windows does not install the PGXS infrastructure by default. What could be the procedure to install PGXS on top of an existing PostgreSQL installation on windows 10 ?

Answer (score 2):

The PostgreSQL extension building infrastructure (PGXS) is not available for Windows, sorry. It's definitely something we'd like to have, but Windows is so different from other children.

As a consequence, building extensions on Windows can be a challenge...

Comment: Thank you Laurenz for the answer. Do you have any idea for installing this extension on windows 10 : https://github.com/MigOpsRepos/pg_dbms_job#readme

Comment: No idea. You'd have to ask the maintainer.